# smoother and nicer animation on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i have made script that makes my page bit better but it has terrible animated script and i want to know how to make it better
best would be slide to side and opacity change to 0

I don't know much about JS this took me week to make it work :S

HTML:

```
        <div id="menu-content">
        <a id="5home" class="show" href="#">Home</a>
        <a id="5contact" class="show" href="#">Contact</a>
        <a id="5about_us" class="show" href="#">About us</a>
        <a id="5a_team" class="show" href="#">A-Team</a>
        <a id="5connect" class="show" href="#">Connect</a>
        <a id="5donate" class="show" href="#">Donate</a>
    </div>

        <div class="cont" id="home" style="Display :visible ;">
        </div>

        <div class="cont" id="contact" style="Display :none ;">
                    </div>

        <div class="cont" id="about_us" style="Display :none ;">
        </div>  

        <div class="cont" id="a_team" style="Display :none ;">
        </div>

        <div class="cont" id="connect" style="Display :none ;">
        </div>  

        <div class="cont" id="donate" style="Display :none ;">
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show').click(function menu() {
        var id = '#';
        id += this.id;
        id = id.replace(/5/, '');
        if ($(id).is(':visible')) {
        }
        else {
            var ido = '#';
            ido += $('.cont:visible').attr('id');
            $(ido).animate({
                opacity: 'toggle',
            }, 350);
            $(id).animate({
                opacity: 'toggle',
            }, 350);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is a plugins named [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) that have much functionnalities.

Function [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) permit to hide some HTML element and fadeIn() to show.

Answer (score 0):

To get a sweet cross-fade effect working on the opacity property just use the animate method jQuery with step and done.
 In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/5vSbn/) you'll find all div in absloute position in a container div with relative position, using index jQuery method all IDs become useless
all jQuery code you need is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.ok').css('opacity','1')
    $('.show').click(function() {
        var ind=$(this).index();
        $('#container').find('div:eq('+ind+')').animate({'opacity':'1'},{
              duration:1000,
              step:function(gox){
                  var op = gox
                  var op = gox < 1 ? (1 - gox) : 0;
                  $('#container').find('div.ok').css('opacity',op)
                 },
              complete:function(){
                  $('#container div').removeClass('ok')
                  $('#container').find('div:eq('+ind+')').addClass('ok')
              }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```